# Time translational symmetry breaking

Tags: energy-conservation, time, symmetry-breaking, time-crystals

I have heard of time translational symmetry, which refers to the law of conservation of energy. [Time crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal) break time translational symmetry. I read on Wikipedia that it only breaks discrete-time translational symmetry and does not affect continuous-time translational symmetry. What exactly do we mean by discrete and continuous-time translational symmetries? How can we predict the motion of such crystals when there is no notion of energy conservation? Where am I going wrong?